# Submitting credit card info through Stripe and validating

Tags: jquery, validation, stripe-payments

I am following Ryan Bates' Railscast on submitting payments to Stripe. He removes the name attribute of the credit card info so that no credit card info gets submitted to the server, only to Stripe through an ajax call.

This doesn't play well with jQuery Validation since it requires a name attribute.

I finally decided to go back to using the name attribute but set it to null in the Stripe callback.

My question is whether this is still a good, secure practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason we recommend not putting the name attributes in the form fields, is so that you can be sure that the inputs will never be submitted to your server. This could happen, for example, if there was a JavaScript error in your client-side code capturing the form submit event.

Having said that, it's just a precaution, not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

For PCI complacency submitting card details via ajax is not recommended. I deal with card processing quite a lot ant the best course of action is:

1. make sure that the page on SSL connection (HTTPS)
2. use the normal form POST method
3. make sure your server configurations follow the PCI compliance requirements
4. never store card details

you can read more about PCI compliance here: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/netsol/ns625/index.html

do note if you follow the proper PCI compliance requirements the company that processes card details will have no problem becoming PCI compliant. A lot of Banks are already started enforcing their clients to follow PCI compliancy as necessary requirement.

Comment: I should note that in this case the card details go straight to Stripe.com, over a SSL connection and is entirely secure and PCI compliant. Stripe has the most stringent level of PCI compliance in the industry.

Comment: Hi Alex, but if you want to submit the details from your website via AJAX then you're submitting from a non secure connection (if you're website doesn't have a SSL certificate) to a secure connection which is not recommended to do with javascript at all. Another thing is how will you handle 3D secure? It would be helpful if you would outline the whole process of your payment (checkout) solution, outlining what you want to achieve in more detail.

Comment: Hey Alex. Yes, we do require merchants to use SSL on their checkout pages, but as long as they're using Stripe.js then they're PCI compliant. As you say, we don't support 3D secure. I should mention that I work at Stripe and wrote the current version of Stripe.js.

Comment: Well it is all down to the developer on what technology he want's to use, in my opinion the simpler technology used the easier it is to maintain a higher level of security. As an example if you use the simple submit method you don't have to worry about JS errors or because of a slow internet connection the javascripts do not finish initiating, this can cause an inconvenience to the customer. The faster and responsive the page is the more likely the customer will finish their checkout and a basket abandonment will not occur.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! Alex 1, I hadn't considered js errors allowing for the accidental submission of the cc info to the servers. I considered simply filtering that info from server logs, but in the end I wrote my own validations—not using jQuery Validation—that only check the length of the cc and presence of cvv. This may result in a handful of extra ajax calls to Stripe but seems safer.